# rdlc Report table in c# does not display all rows from dataset if group by columns are added

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have followed the link given below to group the data and display related records in each table . And the table should repeat for group by criteria defined.

[How to show group by columns on top of the table header instead of on the left in rdlc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196480/how-to-show-group-by-columns-on-top-of-the-table-header-instead-of-on-the-left-I)

I have made all the changes required in the rdlc design and when I ran it , not all the rows are displayed. only first row is displayed and only one table is displayed with only one group by criteria.

Any idea how to fix this ?

I tried removing the group by columns to fix this and now it displays all the records but only under one table ,one group by criteria instead of all the records by group criteria.

Either way I am not able to see the data group by header and table .

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of how your tablix looks?

Comment: Sorry Chris, I found that the records have same data for all the three group by columns. Now I added another record with different value for EmpBand and I made the headers to repeat on new page and page break before start of a new group. This works fine now but  in the new page where I have different group data the group by headers have the same data and didn't get updated( instead have the same header data from previous group by headers).

Comment: Details data is coming correct though. But the only issue now is the group header data is not getting updated before the beginning of new page new group by table data.

Comment: I have repeat on new page true, fixed data as false, Keep with Group to "After" for both group by header row and table header static rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you were able to get the detail data to be grouped properly.

As for the headers, if they are the same, make sure of the following:

1. The tablix cell containing the group header must be inside the group in which you're grouping on the three variables.
2. Make sure you're not referencing the field using an aggregate like "First" or "Last". So long as you're within the scope that contains within it row-level data, then you do not need to use aggregates.

*How Aggregates Look*

```
=First(Fields!FieldX.Value)
```

OR

```
=First(Fields!FieldX.Value,"DataSet1")
```

*How it should look*

```
=Fields!FieldX.Value
```

Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: I have corrected both the table/group headers as per the suggestion 2 above. I am not sure how I would know if its inside the group or outside which is suggestion 1..

Comment: @krrishna You would know that by looking at the brackets on the side of each row. For instance, you can tell a row is a detail row by seeing three horizontal lines stacked on top of each other. A non-detail group is indicated by a bracket that spans multiple rows. The other way to tell is by looking at the Advanced Mode (you can see a screenshot of this in my prior answer on the other question). You'll see indentations in rows as indicating a child-to-parent relationship.

Comment: @krrishna If my answer helped you, please don't forget to upvote it and/or mark it as the correct answer. The reputation points, in addition to the warm fuzzies, are why most of us help others here.